# Get actual value from Python list

Tags: python

Say I have

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [foo(x) for x in a]
```

Now b is something like [ < function  at 0x00F91540>, ...], how do I get python to evaluate b into it's actual values?

--EDIT--

Sorry for the confusion, my frustration is that Python doesn't give me the actual values in b, hence when I try to do something like:

```
b[0] + 1
```

it gives me the below error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?   Right now you are just creating an array of lambda functions take a single parameter.

Comment: Um... your code as it stands doesn't do what you say it does. `b = [foo(x) for x in a]` gives me a list of results, not functions (for a given definition of `foo`, eg. `def foo(x): return x + 1`).

Comment: Can you post the foo(x) function? The code in your updated question should work: b[0] + 1 is a integer plus an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your function outside the comprehension:

```
def foo(x):
    return x + 1

a = [1,2,3]
b = [foo(x) for x in a]
```

Now, `b == [2,3,4]`. Or, as others have pointed out, just use the function body in the list comprehension:

```
[x + 1 for x in a]
```

...although this assumes that you can reproduce the function body in this way (which you won't be able to do for more complicated functions).

Note that the result of a `lambda` expression is the same as typing the name of a function, eg. `lambda x: x+1` and `foo` represent the same thing: a function which needs a parameter given to it and returns a result. For the sake of clarification, this is how you'd "use" a lambda in a list comprehension:

```
[(lambda y: y+1)(x) for x in a]
```

...but seriously, don't do this ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the values, you don't need lambdas at all.
You can simply write:

```
b = [x + 1 for x in a]
```

If, for some reason, you still want to evaluate the lambdas that are in your version of `b`, you can write something like this:

```
c = [f(n) for f, n in zip(b, a)]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want it to do correctly, you don't need the lambda.

```
b = [x+1 for x in a]
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is creating a list of lambda functions what you want is

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [x+1 for x in a]
```